# Need a Proper Data Structure for Handling Message from Multiple Clients

Tags: c, sockets, select

In our application we have a server which will connect to multiple clients. For your reference it is single threaded application . Whenever a client wants to send some message to other client it will go via the server. Whenever a client sends message to the server, it will store the message into a `Dqueue`. Server will extract messages one by one from the `Dqueue` and  it will call `select()` and check whether the channel where the message is supposed to be sent is available or not. If yes it will send, otherwise it will insert it into the back so that we can process other messages.But problem with this approach is that, suppose client `C1` sends two messages `S1` and `S2`. Now when server tries to send `S1` to other client `C2`, C2 was busy as a result it will push the message S1 into the back of the queue. Now Suppose while processing `S2`, client `C2` is ready.So server can now send `S2`. But the problem with this is messages will reach to the `C2` in reverse order (`S2` `S1`).

Can you please suggest what data structure should be suitable for this so that we can maintain the same message order?

Comment: Would it be possible to check if C2 was busy _before_ you pulled the message from the dequeue?

Comment: we can do that but actually we cant wait indefinitely for sending the message. Till the time that socket is busy we want to process other messages for other clients who all are free

Comment: Is there any memory constraint in your system or you can spend memory luxuriously? Which is more important for you? Time or space?

Comment: I would say time is more constraint for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a single queue to handle all messages.  Each client needs its own individual queue.  When a message arrives, determine the client it is destined for and put the message at the end of that client's queue.  Then update your server logic to send only the top message in a given client's queue to that client.  If the client is busy, dont' send the top message.  If the client is ready, send the top message and remove it from that clien's queue.

Comment: But as its in same thread. So how you suggest to process the queue. Suppose I have 5 Clients. So i will create 5 queue.It is not a gud idea to check one by one client if its busy or not. So is there any optimal way to know it. I know select can return the list of free clients. But how we can send message to those clients in one attempt

Comment: You can specify multiple client sockets in a single call to `select()`.  It can tell you which clients are writable. You can then check the queues for just those clients and `send()` any messages that are waiting.  Since you are doing everything in a single thread (why?), you have to use non-blocking or asynchronous socket calls, in which case you can have multiple send operations running at the same time. If you are on Windows, it is best to use asynchronous I/O via OVERLAPPED structures or I/O Completion Ports so you can truely have multiple socket calls running in parallel.

Comment: Remy Yes we are using non blocking socket only and platform is unix. So u mean to say I can iterate all the socket descriptor return by SELECT, then   out element from dqueue for that Descriptor and then send it.

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that `send()` can report a temporary error (`EAGAIN` I think - I'm not a Unix person) at any time when a socket becomes blocked during sending, so I would have each message maintain an offset into its data specifying how many bytes have already been sent. Each time `select()` reports a writable client, `send()` that client's top message, starting at the message's current offset, incrementing the offset by the number of bytes `send()` actually sent. Don't remove that message from the client's queue until the offset reaches the end of the message data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a bunch of things. That is you or someone in your group will be writing the queue manager or the queue manager can accept parameters you create.

Offhand, this sounds like you need an array of structs. Depending on how many clients you think will use the service it could be a fixed array of structs or an allocated block of heap memory. Depending on how you want to manage clients, the array of structs could use pointers to structs or you could allocate enough storage to structs.

I don't know what data you want to store as part of sending a message. Perhaps if you wrote fields down, that would help.

Comment: Actually We need DS because whenver server will receive the message it will first store into the DS. Then it will process the DS to send the message to designated clients. Suppose if its unable to send the message within limited time it will push it back of the DS so that it can process other messages in the DS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Do you mean you have to write a DS?

Comment: Right now we are using Deque for this purpose.But the problem with this as i mentioned above is its changing the order of the message. So I want to know what will be the right Data structure for handling messages

Comment: Without knowing more about the fields involved with what you are doing and not knowing anything about Dequeue, I cannot help you any further. If you were using C++, you could take advantage of some of the dynamic STD objects, but given this in written in C, managing the connection data seems like an array of structures.